# Why the `constructor` points to Object in the following?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, javascript-objects

I read that whenever an object literal is defined, the Object constructor is not called:

```
var ob1 = new Object(); // constructor called
var ob2 = {}; // constructor never called
```

Now consider the following:

```
// a constructor
function Animal (name, food) {
// definition of constructor
}

Animal.prototype = {
    // some properties in the prototype
    // but `constructor` is not set back to Animal
}
```

In the above code, because I am completely overwriting the prototype,  the `constructot` is set to point to `Object`. If I am not wrong, the constructor property is set to point to the constructor which when **called**, causes the prototype to be created. My question is, although I am redefining the prototype completely, the Object constructor isn't called (because it is just an object literal). Then why the `constructor` points to object.

Comment: The `constructor` property isn't typically set by the constructor itself. It's set ahead of time on the prototype for all instances to inherit. When you access `new Animal().constructor`, you're getting the value of `Object.prototype.constructor`.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski please write an answer and elaborate.

Comment: Are you saying that the constructor property is inherited from Object.prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the `constructor` points to object.

The property and its value are being inherited from `Object.prototype`.

```
Animal.prototype.constructor === Object.prototype.constructor; // true
```

Since `Animal.prototype` is an Object instance, created from the literal/initializer, it inherits all properties from `Object.prototype`, including its `constructor`.

---

The `constructor` property is typically assigned on a prototype object and inherited by instances.

The engine sets up that much for you, but only once when a new function is defined.

```
function Animal() {}

console.log(Animal.prototype.constructor); // function Animal() {}
```

That automatic assignment isn't kept when you replace the `prototype` entirely.

```
Animal.prototype = {};

console.log(Animal.prototype.constructor); // function Object() {}
```

The `constructor` property is also just informational. It doesn't actually offer a guarantee of its accuracy, as you've found, since it can easily be altered or overridden.

---

And, invoking a constructor function won't automatically assign the `constructor` property's value for the new instance. At least, unless you define the function to do that explicitly:

```
function Animal() {
    this.constructor = Animal;
}

Animal.prototype = {};

console.log(new Animal().constructor); // function Animal() { ... }
```

Otherwise, since the modified `Animal.prototype` doesn't specifying its own `constructor`...

```
Animal.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // false
```

It inherits that value from its own prototype:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Animal.prototype) === Object.prototype; // true

Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // true

Object.prototype.constructor; // function Object() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the prototype of a constructor, you should always reset the constructor property:

```
Animal.prototype = {
  constructor: Animal
  // some properties in the prototype
};
```

Or, arguably, you should not replace prototypes, only extend them:

```
Object.assign(Animal.prototype, {
  // some properties in the prototype
});
```